# get element in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, .net, repeater

I have a `Repeater` which i am bounding some data to it. Now my problem is how i can refer to the data I have in my label in the repeater from the `javascript`. My code is the following;

**CODEBEHIND**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 // bool boolfound = false;
 string connstring = String.Format("Server=localhost; Port=5432; User Id=postgres; Password=database; Database=valletta;");

 using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring))
 {
  try
   {
    conn.Open();

    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("select get_points('temp_intersect', 'point','id',17339)", conn);
    NpgsqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    currentpoint.DataSource = dr;
    currentpoint.DataBind();

   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "", "$(document).ready(function(){alert('problem with connection')});", true);
   }
 }

}
```

**ASP**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="currentpoint" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <div>
       <asp:Label ID="hiddenlabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("get_points")%>' Visible="false">
       </asp:Label>
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Inspect the HTML where your label is, find the generated Id and use `document.getElementById`

Comment: what have you tried? Where's your javascript function?  have you tried to google your problem? There's about a million pages out there on how to use getelementbyid and getelementbyname in javascript.

Comment: I have already tried this but it seems with no luck: var coordinate = document.getElementById('hiddenlabel'). @Syn123

Comment: No... that's all there is to it > run your page > right click view source > find what's it's being named in the DOM and call that by it's ID.  Ensure it's an Id field & not a Name field.  You're using ASP.NET, ASP.NET applies a naming convention to your Id's, I doubt it's 'hiddenlabel' if it's an asp control in the DOM.  It's more like MasterPageContent_DefaultPageContent_hiddenlabel.

Comment: I think the problem is becausE I am not calling the attribute [text] properly. @Syn123

Comment: when you view the source, can you add to your post the part that refers to the hiddenlabel... not from VS, but from the browser itself.

Comment: This was the issue. Thanks for all your help.  var coordinate = document.getElementById('hiddenlabel').innerHTML.split(','); It works now

Answer (score 3):

You can change the ClientIDMode to  Predictable or static, works well with javascript.

Read [this post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/May/04/Whats-New-in-ASPNET-40-Part-Two-WebForms-and-Visual-Studio-Enhancements)

Comment: I have edited the code like this:<asp:Label ID="hiddenlabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("get_points")%>' Visible="false" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label> BUT I still got null velue when I tried to get the value using the following code: var coordinate = document.getElementById('hiddenlabel');  @Grzegorz B

Comment: I am doing something wrong when it comes to call the attribute.

Comment: You should be using ' ClientIDMode="Predictable"' because you are iterating over a container, then your label would be id='hiddenlabel_0' id='hiddenlabel_1' etc..

Comment: Look at the generated source and find 'get_points' and post generated code

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
document.getElementById('<%=currentpoint.FindControl("hiddenlabel").ClientID%>')
```